# JavaScript clock works on Chrome but doesn't work with Firefox or IE

Tags: javascript, php, html, google-chrome, clock

I'm making a few PHP sites for a client and I have a small problem.

I have a JavaScript text clock located at the top and the bottom of the page (each a copy of the other).

They work perfectly in Chrome, but on Firefox and IE it sometimes doesn't. I've made a new, clean PHP file and attached the JS to check if the problem is from the Javascript file. It doesn't appear to be.

The top clock is GetClock() and the bottom one is GetClockPrint()

Here's the Javascript code for the clock:

```
tday=new Array("Domingo","Segunda-feira","Terça-feira","Quarta-feira","Quinta-feira","Sexta-feira","Sábado");
tmonth=new Array("Janeiro","Fevereiro","Março","Abril","Maio","Junho","Julho","Agosto","Setembro","Outubro","Novembro","Dezembro");

        function GetClock(){
            var d=new Date();
            var nday=d.getDay(),nmonth=d.getMonth(),ndate=d.getDate(),nyear=d.getYear(),nhour=d.getHours(),nmin=d.getMinutes(),nsec=d.getSeconds(),ap;

            if(nyear<1000) nyear+=1900;
            if(nmin<=9) nmin="0"+nmin;
            if(nsec<=9) nsec="0"+nsec;

            document.getElementById('clockbox').innerHTML="<u><h4>"+tday[nday]+", "+ndate+" de "+tmonth[nmonth]+" de "+nyear+", "+nhour+":"+nmin+":"+nsec+"</h4></u>";
            document.getElementById('clockbox2').innerHTML="<u><h4>"+tday[nday]+", "+ndate+" de "+tmonth[nmonth]+" de "+nyear+", "+nhour+":"+nmin+":"+nsec+"</h4></u>";
        }

        function GetClockPrint(){
            var c=new Date();
            var nday=c.getDay(),nmonth=c.getMonth(),ndate=c.getDate(),nyear=c.getYear(),nhour=c.getHours(),nmin=c.getMinutes(),nsec=c.getSeconds(),ap;


            if(nyear<1000) nyear+=1900;
            if(nmin<=9) nmin="0"+nmin;
            if(nsec<=9) nsec="0"+nsec;

            document.getElementById('clockbox2').innerHTML="<u><h4>"+tday[nday]+", "+ndate+" de "+tmonth[nmonth]+" de "+nyear+", "+nhour+":"+nmin+":"+nsec+"</h4></u>";
        }
        window.onload=function(){
            GetClock();
            }
```

And here's the HTML code for the page itself (no PHP code yet)

```
<table align="center"><!-- Botões de submeter/reiniciar e relógio -->
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div align="left">
                        <button type="button" id="restart1" onClick="window.open('../../Index.php','_self')"><img src="../../restart.png">Recomeçar</button>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td valign="middle">
                    <div id="clockbox" align="center"></div>
                </td>
                <td align="right">
                    <div align="right">
                        <button type="button" id="print1" onClick="submeter()"><img src="../../Check.png">Imprimir esta página</button>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
<!-- Start of the second clock code -->
<table align="center">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div align="left">
                    <button type="button" id="restart2" onClick="window.open('../../Index.php','_self')"><img src="../../restart.png">Recomeçar</button>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td valign="middle">
                <div id="clockbox2" align="center"></div>
            </td>
            <td align="right">
                <div align="right">
                    <button type="button" id="print2" onClick="submeter()"><img src="../../Check.png">Imprimir esta página</button>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Please forgive the Portuguese text.
I don't know what's wrong here...
I want the clock to show on IE and Firefox as normally as it shows on Chrome.
Can you guys help me out, please?

I'm using XAMPP to simulate a PHP server. Don't know if that will be helpful.

Thank you in advance

Comment: just as a side note, rather than using a h4 tag inside a u tag ( I think that's wrong nesting) use css to underline the clockbox elems. Some browsers will forgive you and some won't. That may lead to issues

Comment: Testing your code in http://jsfiddle.net/wjwuLj92/ it looks the same to me in Chrome, FF, and IE8 (http://jsfiddle.net/wjwuLj92/embedded/result/). How is the clock not "showing normally" in FF or IE? Is it showing an incorrect string? Is it not showing any string? Please clarify the expected behavior and how it is failing on FF and IE.

Comment: @pete The clocks show up between the buttons in Chrome and in some pages on FF, just like in the jsfiddle, but in IE (don't know which version, sorry) it doesn't show up. the buttons are side by side, without the clocks in the middle.
This project absulutely must be cross-browser...

Comment: Can you find out which versions of IE are affected? Also, can you clarify "in some pages on FF"? Are there "other pages" in FF where the clocks do not appear?

Comment: In IE11 (the one installed on this machine), the clock does not show up.
In FF, in the page I'm working on right now, the same applies. But in Chrome, it shows up just fine. I can provide images, if that would help.

Comment: [link](http://i.imgur.com/lLrYRjJ.png) and [link](http://i.imgur.com/12wN8A8.png)
As you can see, it's the same page, open across 3 different browsers, all of them with Javascript enabled, but they don't behave as they should... Only Chrome is behaving as expected.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the problem. I suspect it may be a problem with other code in your PHP file, or maybe caused by your DTD.

Comment: @pete I've set up the site completely, it's now optimized to Chrome. And since I have a few more days to work on it, I went into   FF, and I removed a body onload function, and now the clock works well on FF. The thing is, I need the onload function. I'll try to cross out as many JS stuff as I can, as I believe that's where the problem stems from.

Comment: Is this a public site that we can visit and see the problem?

Comment: @pete No, it's a private site for a fire department. If I can't figure out what the problem is, I'll just tell them to use Google Chrome :D

Comment: "I went into FF, and I removed **a** body onload function". Can you set up a jsFiddle that reproduces the problem?

Comment: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/poseavx0/) It's weird, because the result in firefox isn't the same as the fiddle's...

Answer (score 1):

I used http://jsfiddle.net/poseavx0/1/ instead of your fiddle (you had an extra `}` at the end, and you had it set to run `'onLoad` instead of `No wrap  - in <head>`, so your `window.onload` would never fire).

I was still unable to duplicate the problem.

I can only assume that you have/had multiple `window.onload` calls where subsequent calls to `window.onload` would overwrite previous calls because of your comment "I went into FF, and I removed **a** body onload function" (emphasis mine).

The solution to this could be to set up your `window.onload` as you did in your fiddle:

```
window.onload = function () {
    // call as many functions as you want in here
};
```

[Billy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4118466/billy) had a very valid point regarding the clocks, although it would not affect the display. Your CSS for `#clockbox` and `#clockbox2` really should be:

```
#clockbox, #clockbox2 {
    text-decoration:underline;
    margin: 1.33em 0;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Also, *in your fiddle, you do not have an element with an `id` of `clockbox2`*. Instead, it seems to be called `relogio2` (based on the markup) but your JavaScript does not reflect this name change. As such, `clockbox2` cannot be set.

Overall, you could probably benefit from a decent cross-browser event attaching routine.

```
var addHandler = function addHandler(object, event, handler, useCapture) {
    var existingHandlers,
        o = typeof object === 'string' ? document.getElementById(object) : object;
    useCapture = !!useCapture; // coerce to boolean
    if ('addEventListener' in o) {
        o.addEventListener(event, handler, useCapture);
    } else if ('attachEvent' in o) {
        o.attachEvent(event, handler);
    } else {
        existingHandlers = o['on' + event];
        if (existingHandlers) {
            o['on' + event] = function (e) {
                existingHandlers(e);
                handler(e);
            };
        } else {
            o['on' + event] = handler;
        }
    }
};
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/poseavx0/2/ for that in action (which also refactors most of your JavaScript).

Comment: I've been messinig around with the JS code, and I seem to have identified the source of the problem. It seems that when AtribMorada, which is a function to post data from localStorage, loads on pageload, the clock doesn't show up.
But when I created a button to run AtribMorada, there was no problem with the clock.
I leave it like this, but the goal is for the site to be as automated as it can...
I'll make a small version of the site, with one or 2 pages + the index, and see if you guys can get it to work.
BTW, keep the JS to the basics, if you can. I don't know jQuery or any of that...

Comment: @RobSp1derp1g: There is no jQuery in that bottom fiddle. It's all plain-vanilla JavaScript. I merely rewrote your functions to make them a little more efficient (and give you examples of better practices). If there's a way to get in to a chat session with you, I'll happily explain why I refactored your code the way I did. Is there a chance you can update your fiddle to include the `AtribMorada` function where it loads on pageload and causes the problem?

Answer (score 0):

U can use muse..

Paste in this code an it will work.

```
<table align="center"><!-- Botões de submeter/reiniciar e relógio -->
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div align="left">
                        <button type="button" id="restart1" onClick="window.open('../../Index.php','_self')"><img src="../../restart.png">Recomeçar</button>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td valign="middle">
                    <div id="clockbox" align="center"></div>
                </td>
                <td align="right">
                    <div align="right">
                        <button type="button" id="print1" onClick="submeter()"><img src="../../Check.png">Imprimir esta página</button>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
<!-- Start of the second clock code -->
<table align="center">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div align="left">
                    <button type="button" id="restart2" onClick="window.open('../../Index.php','_self')"><img src="../../restart.png">Recomeçar</button>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td valign="middle">
                <div id="clockbox2" align="center"></div>
            </td>
            <td align="right">
                <div align="right">
                    <button type="button" id="print2" onClick="submeter()"><img src="../../Check.png">Imprimir esta página</button>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: I'm afraid it still doesn't work... It seems to be the same as the code I posted.
Also, I'm using Dreamweaver.